# Normalization techniques for PDF

Tags: reference-request, probability-distributions, numerical-methods

I have a function  $$f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ which I would like to use as a probability density function. In order to do this I need to find a normalization constant $c$ so that when I integrate over all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ I get $1$. I can't find an analytic solution to $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)dx$$ and I don't expect one exists. I can however prove the integral is bounded. I'm looking for numerical techniques that can help me find $c$. The problem is $n$ can be large, on the order of $1000$ so typical numerical integration techniques fail. I have frequently heard it mentioned in the probability literature that this problem is easy, but I have never seen the techniques used. Can people suggest some approaches to finding $c$ in this context?

Comment: have you tried Monte Carlo integration?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration

Comment: @GregoryGrant I have played with this. I find it pretty tricky to construct a good sampling plan in high dimensions. Been reading about MCMC too, not sure if this is applicable.

Comment: How does your function look like? Is it spead out in space or focused around a single point(s)? I think there is a better chance of getting a good answer if you add some more details / context.

Comment: @Winther $f(x)$ can come from one of many different families of functions I have designed. I need some broad techniques that I can apply to them all.

Comment: Well almost all the standard methods of integration (like quadrature) are out of the window as soon as the dimension gets large enough. In many cases something like $D\sim 5-10$ is already too large and $D=1000$ is definitely too large. Monte-Carlo integration and related variants (such as quasi-MC, MC with importance sampling) are usually the only methods that have any chance of evaluating such integrals in a reasonable amount of time so I would suggest you check it out.